# SoundEngine sample leaks

Tags: iphone, audio

I use SoundEngine sample from CrashLanding sample Iphone SDK.
When i run my project i found small memory leaks when sound engine initialize.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug prior SDK 2.2. I think the bug was fixed from SDK 2.2 on. But if you are compiling for SDK 2.2+ use AVAudioPlayer instead.

Comment: I tested on all sdk (2.1/2.2.1/3.0b5) CrachLanding and oalTouch sample have memory leaks on all this sdk.

Comment: That's what I've read when I was working on sound. I ended up using AVAudioPlayer instead, we needed to compile to 2.2 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should be moving away from SoundEngine. I've heard people say that the switch to AVAudioPlayer is reasonably easy.

However, I wish Apple had just kept CrashLanding up-to-date. I've never seen anything comparable to it for learning the hardware in a hurry. Someone should step up to the plate with something that makes it as easy to do a 2D sprite game as CrashingLanding did. A lot of people learned from that code.